# What's a good icon for symbolising "rent"?

Tags: icon, interface-design, user-experience

"rent" as in renting of books etc.

I need to design a rent icon that symbolizes renting of books in a mobile app.

Comment: Did you search for anything yourself, and what were the reasons to discard what you found?

Answer (score 0):

How about a book with a superimposed timer or arrow?